# Rewrite escaped hashtag # %23

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I recently noticed some incoming 404 error hits from URLs with their hashtag escaped.

Correct URL structure:
`http://example.org/#!/thepage` or `/index.html#!/thepage`

Escaped/ Incorrect URL:
`http://example.org/%23!/thepage`

I tried the following .htaccess rule with little success:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^%23!/(.*)$ /index.html#!/$1 [NE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this answer which pointed me into the right direction: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/76059

Here is the rule that worked for me

```
RewriteRule ^\x23!/(.*)$ http://www.example.org/index.html#!/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

When using `\x` it will match escaped characters starting with `%`